# How to extracting abstract about entities and the relations between entities?

Tags: rapidminer, gate

I want to use rapidminer or gate to extract abstract about entities(Characters) (or just main characteristics) and the relations between entities in a story. Do you have an idea or sample i can modify to that aim?

I tried to use extensions with rapid miner like Aylien and Rosette, but the extract entities operator asks about an attribute parameter, and I couldn't discover what its value about? where to get it? and how to continue with finding the relations between entities?

Answer (score 0):

when using the *Extract Entities* operator fro mthe Aylien extension for RapidMiner, the input attribute parameter should be the attribute (column in the example set) that contains the text examples you want to analyze.

For more inspiration take a look at the text mining section of the [RapidMiner Community](https://community.rapidminer.com/t5/RapidMiner-Text-Analytics-Web/tkb-p/Text).